# Not Important bug found with 5 second comment warning?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-comments, warning

This is not an important bug to fix, but just noticed it today. You normaly get the 5 seconds between comment vote warning when you try and vote for too many comments at once.  I deleted two of my comments back to back on the same question and I got that same warning

[image: popup]

You can replicate it by making two comments and then delete them both quickly.

Like I said, not important to fix anytime soon, but noted.

Comment: I noticed this too a couple of days ago.

Comment: We try to have throttles on everything in the system - not only for our servers' health, but more importantly, to prevent/minimize abuse from scripts.

Comment: Oh I agree with you completely. I just thought maybe it should say you couldnt delete instead of comment vote, but as Ian said, it counts as a "vote to delete" so it makes sense to me now why it says that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deleting a comment counts as a 'vote to delete'. That being said it only takes one vote, and your own.

**Edit**
Just to verify that I'm not lying, deleting a comment is

```
 VoteTypeId = 10 //(http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/###/vote/10)
```

[Here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/#comment-24147) is the list of vote types, where 10 is clearly marked as deletion. Normal up-votes have a type of 2.  So the message is correct, you're limited to 1 vote every 5 seconds.

Comment: Wow. Clear-cut case of developer reasoning.

Comment: That's how it's coded, so that's what we meant? ;)